# How to deny access by default using apollo server with GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, authorize

I'm trying to configure GraphQL to work with an external Authorize Service. I would like to use the service to lock down mutations and queries by default unless a directive is applied which calls the service to open up permissions.

I was thinking this could be accomplished if I was able to execute code that only runs if no directive is applied.

Thank you!

Comment: You are thinking about having an "auth" directive call an external authorization service each time there is a request? That, on the surface, seems like a lot of overhead. There is no way in having the requester provide their credentials with their request? e.g. a JWT.

Comment: The JWT authenticates the service, but the Authorize Service is intended to give or take away permissions to each resource based on their role so a user can't access the resources of other users once they are already logged in.

Comment: The JWT can contain your authorization information, like roles, etc. It is also signed so you know it came from where you expected. If the Authorize service changes a user's role it will be reflected in the token they send along with the user.  If it isn't, you may be able to add that data to it through configuration. Not knowing the Authorization service used, it is impossible to guess.